# Uso delle maiuscole con nomi di discipline scientifiche e branche della conoscenza

Tags: orthography, capitalization

Mi è venuto questo dubbio perché ieri ho voluto scrivere in italiano una frase su un mio professore e, veramente, non sapevo come dovesse farlo: *il mio professore di Relatività Generale*? *il mio professore di Relatività generale*? oppure *il mio professore di relatività generale*?

Per la lingua spagnola, le regole di uso delle maiuscole per i nomi di discipline scientifiche sono riportate su questa [pagina della *Ortografía de la lengua española*](http://aplica.rae.es/orweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=UGxdQRValgAQHkQp) della Real Academia  Española e la Asociación de Academias de la Lengua Española.

Si spiega che, in generale, i sostantivi e gli aggettivi che fanno parte del nome delle discipline scientifiche e le varie branche della conoscenza si devono scrivere con le minuscole, come in questi esempi:

> - La física nuclear ha experimentado grandes avances en los últimos años.
> - La morfología es una parte de la gramática.
> - Tiene un talento especial para las matemáticas.
> - La psicología infantil es muy complicada.

La maiuscola iniziale si deve usare soltanto per designare studi o materie regolamentate in contesti accademici. Ecco alcuni esempi:

> - Soy licenciada en Filología Inglesa.
> - Me he matriculado en Arquitectura.
> - ¿Quién te da Física este año?

"Licenciada" significa "laureata". "Me he matriculado" vuol dire "mi sono iscritto/a". Nell'ultima frase si sta chiedendo chi sia l'insegnante di Fisica (inteso come materia scolastica: non so se in italiano si deve scrivere così, con la maiuscola iniziale) di quest'anno.

Più in dettaglio, si afferma che i sostantivi e gli aggettivi che fanno parte del nome di una materia o corso di studio si devono scrivere con la maiuscola iniziale, tanto se il nome di questa materia o corso coincide o no con il nome di una scienza o disciplina. Ma se il nome di una materia o corso risulta eccessivamente lungo, allora si scrive con la maiuscola iniziale unicamente la prima parola.

Ad esempio,

> Inglés, Lengua, Matemáticas, Conocimiento del Medio, Química Orgánica, Lenguaje Publicitario, Metodología de la Programación

invece

> Introducción al comentario de textos narrativos y poéticos españoles del
> siglo XVI.

Le regole per l'italiano sono le stesse? O alcuna di queste regole è diversa?

Ho cercato al primo capitolo dell'*Italiano* di Serianni, sulla sezione dedicata all'uso delle maiuscole, ma non ho trovato nulla al riguardo.

Comment: Empiricamente, direi che in italiano sia simile, magari restringendo le maiuscole ai nomi ufficiali di corsi ed esami (Analisi I, Istituzioni di geometria superiore... con le maiuscole opzionali per le parole successive alla prima).

Comment: Ah, OK, @DaG, ma se si sta parlando di un corso di studio, si scrive Relatività Generale, Relatività generale o si può scegliere tra ambedue?

Comment: Ho visto fare in entrambi i modi. Personalmente, usare le maiuscole per le eventuali parole dopo la prima mi sembra eccessivo, quasi pomposo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Il seguente estratto, dall’[Università La Sapienza](https://www.uniroma1.it/sites/default/files/allegati/linee_guida_semplificazione_testi_21_09_2015_0.pdf),  potrebbe essere un utile riferimento:

> L’uso di maiuscolo e minuscolo per i sostantivi è un argomento complesso, sul quale si è discusso molto nell’ambito della comunicazione pubblica........

> Questo uso del maiuscolo è in realtà più diffuso di quanto si creda: ogni organizzazione tende a utilizzare la lettera iniziale maiuscola per le parole che indicano cose importanti nella propria attività: un dipartimento universitario di astronomia potrebbe scrivere “Stelle” maiuscolo, un dipartimento medico tenderà a scrivere sempre “Medicina” in maiuscolo.

> ***In questa varietà definire una regola rigida è difficile: più che mai nell’uso di maiuscolo e minuscolo chi scrive dovrà affidarsi anche al buon senso stilistico e comunicativo.***
> È necessario infine ricordare che l’eccesso di maiuscole riduce la leggibilità dei testi, provocando problemi soprattutto alle persone ipovedenti.

Comment: Ah, grazie, @Hachi. Allora, se ho capito bene, in italiano non ci sono regole precise al riguardo e questo significa che, per quel dubbio concreto che avevo avuto, dalle tre possibilità che ho menzionato, posso scegliere quella che mi piaccia di più, no?

Comment: @Charo - ci sono delle regole ma per casi come quello che proponi tu diventa più che altro una questione di stile e preferenze personali.

Comment: Voglio dire che non ci sono regole precise per quello che chiedo nella domanda, non per l'uso delle maiuscole in generale.